# React Native how to call onPress event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello there i am working on a beginner project of mine with React Native and right now i am not able to handle `onPress` event.

**Render**:

```
_renderRow(feed) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow()}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: feed.thumbnail}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}/>
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{feed.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

And the `onPress` function

```
_pressRow() {
  console.log('list item pressed')  
}
```

**Listview**

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this._renderRow}
  style={styles.listView}/>
```

This is what i get as an error.

> undefined is not a function (evaluating _this3._pressRow())

### **EDIT**

Thanks to @Cherniv. I forgot to bind `this` with the renderRow function, changed my code like that and worked as intended:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
    style={styles.listView}/>
```

Comment: seems like you forgot to bind `_renderRow` itself, something like: `renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this, feed)}`

Comment: hmm i will have a look, this is how my renderRow looks now  `renderRow={this._renderRow}`

Comment: @Cherniv yes you were right about the missing bind

Comment: cool, you are welcome

Comment: You can not use more than one child in TouchableHighlight. I d'ont think your use of TouchableHighlight is right. 
ref : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html
NOTE: TouchableHighlight must have one child (not zero or more than one)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because you forgot the "_" before pressRow in method declaration ?

Comment: sorry this is just from the copy paste

Comment: have you check the value of feed and if the function _renderRow is called correctly?

Comment: @NBeydib feed looks ok, so is the list, everything works fine except from that onPress event